# Parse: Match query with query to pointer

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfquery

So I'm trying to get all UserSports that has a user (pointer to User) with the matching facebookId in User from facebookIdList. facebookIdList contains the id:s. But objects has 0 values. Any ideas?

```
let userQuery = PFQuery(className: "User")
userQuery.whereKey("facebookId", containedIn: facebookIdList)

let query = PFQuery(className: "UserSport")
query.whereKey("user", matchesQuery: userQuery)
query.includeKey("user")

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
  if error == nil {
    if let userSports = objects as? [UserSport] {      
      print(userSports)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try executing the User query by itself to make sure it's returning what you expect

Comment: What @Russell said. Also, double check that your keys match. They're case sensitive, so maybe you have a "User" key instead of "user", or "faceBookId" instead of "facebookId"

Additionally, I know that the objective-c SDK has a specific query for users that you're supposed to use ( [PFUser query] ), so perhaps there is a similar thing for Swift. I bet that your userQuery isn't querying the User class the way you'd expect it to be.

Comment: Good catch @Jake T., The problem is definitely that that he is incorrectly querying for Users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you aren't querying the User class properly.  See [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26169489/4544328).  You should be using the class "_User", or, more appropriately, `var query : PFQuery = PFUser.query()` instead of `var query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")`