# Retrieve User info from Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform, xcode7

I am coding an app and have user upon the user logging in I would like to take them to their dashboard and display info regarding their account. I am trying to display the username in a label but am having issues retrieving it. I am using the following code:

```
func getData(){
    var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "User")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: "actualUsername")
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (object: PFObject!, error: NSError!) - >Void; in
        if object != nil {
        NSLog("Success!")

        } else {

            NSLog("something went wrong")

        }

    }
```

I am using swift and xcode7

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`currentUser`](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFUser.html#//api/name/currentUser) property of the `PFUser` object. This returns the informations about the user who is currently logged in. Then you can access the username etc:

```
PFUser.currentUser.username
```

Comment: so it would be "self.usernamelabel.text = PFUser.currentUser.username" ?

Comment: I attempted that but it didnt work, im not sure if this is the proper way to do it but this worked: "var user = PFUser.currentUser()
            userName.text = user?.username" just incase anyone runs across this

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the class you're querying, "User", doesn't exist.  It's actually "_User", though it is more proper to use `var query : PFQuery = PFUser.query()` [(see this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26169489/4544328)

Christian isn't wrong, though. If you have a user signed in, PFUser.currentUser returns the current user. So create a user PFUser variable and assign PFUser.currentUser to it, then you can access the elements using `user["username"]`

Comment: ok so I now have                                                                                               var findUsers:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!;
            findUsers.whereKey("username",  equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)   How do I place that text into the label?

Comment: Since you are displaying the information of the logged in user, querying for the user is a completely unnecessary network call. 

var user: PFUser = PFUser.currentUser; 
var username: string (or NSString? I don't know swift) = user["username"];

Your label should have a setText method.  I'm not familiar with Swift, I use Obj-C, so I can't help you with the syntax of calling it.